# Why does NServiceBus on Azure append ".events" to my Topic names?

Tags: azure, nservicebus, nservicebus5

I have an Azure Topic called "response1" and I would like to subscribe to messages sent to the topic using NServiceBus.

My problem is that instead of subscribing to response1, NServiceBus creates a new Topic on azure called response1.events and subscribes to that. Why does NServiceBus add ".events" to some things? And how do I stop this behavior?

**Additional information:**

My configuration:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NServiceBus/Transport"
        connectionString="Endpoint=sb://[my-namespace].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=[issuer];SharedSecretValue=[key]"></add>

</connectionStrings>
```

Subscription configuration:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>

        <add Assembly="Messages" Type="Messages.TheResponse" Endpoint="response1"/>

    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

And my bus configuration in code (console application):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Subscribing...");

        BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
        busConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
        busConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();

        Console.WriteLine("Configuring bus...");
        bus = NServiceBus.Bus.Create(busConfiguration).Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Done. Press Enter to Exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Why does NServiceBus on Azure not use my specified endpoint name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750322/why-does-nservicebus-on-azure-not-use-my-specified-endpoint-name/30787162#30787162)

Nsb has been designed not do this, business endpoints can only subscribe to other business endpoints, not to stand alone technical constructs like topics.

PS: if this is related to your integration question, and your intend is to publish to a native topic not associated to an business endpoint, then you can do it the same way as done in the integration sample

Comment: Thanks Yves. I had to change my thinking a bit... like you said, a standalone queue or topic is not the important thing, the EndPoint is the important thing. So I now have one endpoint, let's call it "MyBusiness". Consumers can send commands to MyBusiness (the queue name) and subscribe to events on "MyBusiness.Events".